Error when starting Tensorflow Extended Evaluator component
If the bug is related to a specific library below, please raise an issue in the
respective repo directly: Evaluator component
TensorFlow Data Validation Repo
TensorFlow Model Analysis Repo
TensorFlow Transform Repo
TensorFlow Serving Repo
System information

Have I specified the code to reproduce the issue (Yes, No): Yes
Environment in which the code is executed (e.g., Local(Linux/MacOS/Windows),
Interactive Notebook, Google Cloud, etc): GCP Vertex Workbench
TensorFlow version: 2.13.0
TFX Version: 1.14.0
Python version: 3.10
Python dependencies (from pip freeze output):

Package                         Version
------------------------------- --------------
absl-py                         1.4.0
anyio                           4.3.0
apache-beam                     2.50.0
appnope                         0.1.3
argon2-cffi                     23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings            21.2.0
array-record                    0.5.0
arrow                           1.3.0
asttokens                       2.4.1
astunparse                      1.6.3
async-lru                       2.0.4
attrs                           21.4.0
Babel                           2.14.0
backcall                        0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                  4.12.3
bleach                          6.1.0
Brotli                          1.1.0
cached-property                 1.5.2
cachetools                      5.3.3
certifi                         2024.2.2
cffi                            1.16.0
charset-normalizer              3.3.2
click                           8.1.7
cloudpickle                     2.2.1
comm                            0.2.2
contourpy                       1.2.0
crcmod                          1.7
cycler                          0.12.1
debugpy                         1.8.1
decorator                       5.1.1
defusedxml                      0.7.1
dill                            0.3.1.1
dm-tree                         0.1.8
dnspython                       2.6.1
docker                          4.4.4
docopt                          0.6.2
docstring_parser                0.16
entrypoints                     0.4
et-xmlfile                      1.1.0
etils                           1.7.0
exceptiongroup                  1.2.0
executing                       2.0.1
fastavro                        1.9.4
fasteners                       0.19
fastjsonschema                  2.19.1
flatbuffers                     24.3.25
fonttools                       4.50.0
fqdn                            1.5.1
fsspec                          2024.2.0
gast                            0.4.0
google-api-core                 2.12.0
google-api-python-client        1.12.11
google-apitools                 0.5.31
google-auth                     2.29.0
google-auth-httplib2            0.1.1
google-auth-oauthlib            1.0.0
google-cloud-aiplatform         1.45.0
google-cloud-bigquery           2.34.4
google-cloud-bigquery-storage   2.22.0
google-cloud-bigtable           2.21.0
google-cloud-core               2.4.1
google-cloud-datastore          2.18.0
google-cloud-dlp                3.12.3
google-cloud-language           2.11.1
google-cloud-pubsub             2.18.4
google-cloud-pubsublite         1.8.3
google-cloud-recommendations-ai 0.10.5
google-cloud-resource-manager   1.12.3
google-cloud-spanner            3.40.1
google-cloud-storage            2.14.0
google-cloud-videointelligence  2.11.4
google-cloud-vision             3.4.5
google-crc32c                   1.5.0
google-pasta                    0.2.0
google-resumable-media          2.7.0
googleapis-common-protos        1.63.0
grpc-google-iam-v1              0.13.0
grpcio                          1.59.2
grpcio-status                   1.48.2
h11                             0.14.0
h2                              4.1.0
h5py                            3.10.0
hdfs                            2.7.3
hpack                           4.0.0
httpcore                        1.0.5
httplib2                        0.22.0
httpx                           0.27.0
hyperframe                      6.0.1
idna                            3.6
imageio                         2.34.0
importlib_metadata              7.1.0
importlib_resources             6.4.0
ipykernel                       6.29.3
ipython                         7.34.0
ipython-genutils                0.2.0
ipywidgets                      7.8.1
isoduration                     20.11.0
jedi                            0.19.1
Jinja2                          3.1.3
joblib                          1.3.2
Js2Py                           0.74
json5                           0.9.24
jsonpointer                     2.4
jsonschema                      4.17.3
jsonschema-specifications       2023.12.1
jupyter                         1.0.0
jupyter_client                  7.4.9
jupyter-console                 6.6.3
jupyter_core                    5.7.2
jupyter-events                  0.10.0
jupyter-lsp                     2.2.4
jupyter_server                  2.13.0
jupyter_server_terminals        0.4.4
jupyterlab                      4.1.5
jupyterlab-pygments             0.2.2
jupyterlab_server               2.25.4
jupyterlab-widgets              1.1.7
keras                           2.13.1
keras-tuner                     1.4.7
kiwisolver                      1.4.5
kt-legacy                       1.0.5
kubernetes                      12.0.1
lazy_loader                     0.3
libclang                        18.1.1
Markdown                        3.6
MarkupSafe                      2.1.5
matplotlib                      3.8.1
matplotlib-inline               0.1.6
mistune                         3.0.2
ml-dtypes                       0.2.0
ml-metadata                     1.14.0
ml-pipelines-sdk                1.14.0
nbclassic                       1.0.0
nbclient                        0.10.0
nbconvert                       7.16.3
nbformat                        5.10.3
nest_asyncio                    1.6.0
networkx                        3.2.1
notebook                        6.5.6
notebook_shim                   0.2.4
numpy                           1.24.3
nvidia-cublas-cu12              12.4.2.65
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12          12.2.142
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12           12.2.140
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12        12.4.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu12               9.0.0.312
nvidia-cufft-cu12               11.0.8.103
nvidia-curand-cu12              10.3.3.141
nvidia-cusolver-cu12            11.5.2.141
nvidia-cusparse-cu12            12.3.0.142
nvidia-nccl-cu12                2.16.5
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12           12.4.99
nvidia-tensorrt                 99.0.0
oauth2client                    4.1.3
oauthlib                        3.2.2
objsize                         0.6.1
opencv-python                   4.9.0.80
openpyxl                        3.1.2
opt-einsum                      3.3.0
orjson                          3.10.0
overrides                       6.5.0
packaging                       20.9
pandas                          1.5.3
pandocfilters                   1.5.0
parso                           0.8.3
pexpect                         4.9.0
pickleshare                     0.7.5
pillow                          10.2.0
pip                             24.0
pkgutil_resolve_name            1.3.10
platformdirs                    4.2.0
portpicker                      1.6.0
prometheus_client               0.20.0
promise                         2.3
prompt-toolkit                  3.0.42
proto-plus                      1.23.0
protobuf                        3.20.3
psutil                          5.9.8
ptyprocess                      0.7.0
pure-eval                       0.2.2
pyarrow                         10.0.1
pyasn1                          0.6.0
pyasn1_modules                  0.4.0
pycparser                       2.21
pydantic                        1.10.14
pydot                           1.4.2
pyfarmhash                      0.3.2
Pygments                        2.17.2
pyjsparser                      2.7.1
pymongo                         4.6.3
pyparsing                       3.1.2
pyrsistent                      0.20.0
PySocks                         1.7.1
python-dateutil                 2.9.0
python-json-logger              2.0.7
pytz                            2024.1
PyYAML                          6.0.1
pyzmq                           24.0.1
qtconsole                       5.5.1
QtPy                            2.4.1
referencing                     0.34.0
regex                           2023.12.25
requests                        2.31.0
requests-oauthlib               2.0.0
rfc3339-validator               0.1.4
rfc3986-validator               0.1.1
rpds-py                         0.18.0
rsa                             4.9
scikit-learn                    1.3.2
scipy                           1.12.0
Send2Trash                      1.8.2
setuptools                      69.2.0
shapely                         2.0.3
six                             1.16.0
sniffio                         1.3.1
soupsieve                       2.5
sqlparse                        0.4.4
stack-data                      0.6.2
tensorboard                     2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server         0.7.2
tensorflow                      2.13.1
tensorflow-data-validation      1.14.0
tensorflow-datasets             4.9.3
tensorflow-estimator            2.13.0
tensorflow-hub                  0.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem    0.36.0
tensorflow-metadata             1.14.0
tensorflow-model-analysis       0.45.0
tensorflow-model-optimization   0.8.0
tensorflow-recommenders         0.7.3
tensorflow-serving-api          2.13.1
tensorflow-transform            1.14.0
tensorrt                        8.6.1.post1
tensorrt-bindings               8.6.1
tensorrt-libs                   8.6.1
termcolor                       2.4.0
terminado                       0.18.1
tfx                             1.14.0
tfx-bsl                         1.14.0
threadpoolctl                   3.4.0
tifffile                        2024.2.12
tinycss2                        1.2.1
toml                            0.10.2
tomli                           2.0.1
tornado                         6.4
tqdm                            4.66.2
traitlets                       5.14.2
types-python-dateutil           2.9.0.20240316
typing_extensions               4.10.0
typing-utils                    0.1.0
tzlocal                         5.2
uri-template                    1.3.0
uritemplate                     3.0.1
urllib3                         2.2.1
wcwidth                         0.2.13
webcolors                       1.13
webencodings                    0.5.1
websocket-client                1.7.0
Werkzeug                        3.0.1
wheel                           0.43.0
widgetsnbextension              3.6.6
wrapt                           1.16.0
zipp                            3.17.0
zstandard                       0.22.0

Describe the current behavior
This is the code I am using to replicate the code.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from callbacks import *


def setup_pretrained_model(args):
    """
    Function to load pretrained model
    """
    IMG_SHAPE = (args["input_dim"], args["input_dim"], 3)
    # Transfer learning model with MobileNetV3
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Large(
        input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet',
        minimalistic=True
    )
    # Freeze the pre-trained model weights
    base_model.trainable = False
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(base_model.output)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name="top_dropout")(x)
    if return_logits:
        # Return logits if return_logits is True
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(args["num_classes"])(x)
    else:
        # Return softmax probabilities (original behavior)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(args["num_classes"], activation='sigmoid')(x)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(base_model.input, x)
    return model

def _input_fn(file_pattern, batch_size):
    # Define how to parse the example
    feature_description = {
        'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'image/label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    }
    
    def _parse_function(example_proto):
        features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
        # Decode the JPEG image
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(features['image/encoded'], channels=3)
        # Resize the image to a fixed size (adjust as needed)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [224, 224])
        label = features['image/label']
        return image, label
    
    # Load and parse the data
    # path/file.gz path/*
    
    all_files = tf.io.gfile.glob(file_pattern)
    filtered_files = [file for file in all_files if file.endswith('.gz')]
    
    print("file pattern in input_fn : ", file_pattern)
    print("filtered files : ", filtered_files)
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filtered_files, compression_type='GZIP')
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    
    return dataset
        
def fit_model(fn_args, args):
    try:
        model = setup_pretrained_model(args)
        # model.summary()
        
        model.compile(
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr_schedule), 
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy']
        )
        
        hist = model.fit(
            fn_args.train_data,
            validation_data=fn_args.eval_data,
            epochs=fn_args.train_steps,
            callbacks=[
                early_stopping(),
            ],
        )
        return model

    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        print("Training Stopped. Check the log.")

def run_fn(fn_args):    
    train_dataset = _input_fn(fn_args.train_files[0], 16)
    eval_dataset = _input_fn(fn_args.eval_files[0], 16)
    fn_args.train_data = train_dataset
    fn_args.eval_data = eval_dataset
    hist = fit_model(fn_args, args)    

    

from tfx.components import Trainer
from tfx.proto import trainer_pb2
from tfx.dsl.components.base import executor_spec
from tfx.components.trainer.executor import GenericExecutor
from tfx.types import channel_utils

qat_trainer = Trainer(
    module_file='model.py',
    examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'],
    train_args=trainer_pb2.TrainArgs(num_steps=100),
    eval_args=trainer_pb2.EvalArgs(num_steps=100),
)

eval_config = tfma.EvalConfig(
    model_specs=[
        tfma.ModelSpec(signature_name="serving_default", label_key="image/label"),
    ],
    metrics_specs=[
        tfma.MetricsSpec(metrics=[
            tfma.MetricConfig(class_name="SparseCategoricalAccuracy",
                              threshold=tfma.MetricThreshold(
                                  value_threshold=tfma.GenericValueThreshold(lower_bound={"value": 0.8}),
                              ))
        ])
    ],
    slicing_specs=[
        # Evaluate metrics for all data
        tfma.SlicingSpec()
        # Example of slicing spec if you want to analyze performance for specific slices
        # tfma.SlicingSpec(feature_keys=["some_feature_key"])
    ]
)

# Now, to integrate this into the TFX pipeline, use the Evaluator component:
evaluator = components.Evaluator(
    examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'],
    model=trainer.outputs['model'],
    eval_config=eval_config,
)


context.run(evaluator)

WARNING:absl:Large batch_size 1 failed with error Fail to call signature func with signature_name: serving_default.
              the inputs are:
['bytes_as_images'].
              The input_specs are:
 {'input_7': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_7')}.. Attempting to run batch through serially. Note that this will significantly affect the performance.

also, this error message
TypeError: Binding inputs to tf.function signature_wrapperfailed due totoo many positional arguments. Received args: (<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=string, numpy=
Describe the expected behavior
Evaluator should be instantiated.
Standalone code to reproduce the issue
I have used test code to evaulate the model and it gives 99% of accuracy, but can't seem to use Evaluator.
import tensorflow as tf
import os

model_uri = qat_trainer.outputs['model'].get()[0].uri
print(os.listdir(model_uri))
print(os.listdir(model_uri + "/Format-Serving/"))

loaded_model2 = tf.saved_model.load(model_uri + "/Format-Serving/")
# print(os.listdir(loaded_model2))
print(list(loaded_model2.signatures.keys())) 

print(example_gen.outputs['examples'])

def _parse_function(example_proto):
    # Define your parsing schema
    image_feature_description = {
        'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'image/label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    }
    # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the schema
    features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature_description)
    
    # Decode the JPEG image
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(features['image/encoded'], channels=3)
    
    # Apply any additional preprocessing: resizing, normalization, etc.
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [224, 224])
    # image = image / 255.0  # Normalize to [0, 1] if required by your model
    
    label = features['image/label']  # Assuming you have labels and need them
    return image, label

import numpy as np

def get_dataset_from_tfrecords(tfrecord_files, batch_size=16):
    print("tfrecord files in get dataset from tfrecords")
    # print(os.listdir(tfrecord_files))
    # Create a tf.data.Dataset from TFRecord files
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_files, compression_type="GZIP")
    # Apply your parsing and preprocessing function
    parsed_dataset = raw_dataset.map(_parse_function)
    # Batch the dataset
    batched_dataset = parsed_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    
    return batched_dataset

# Usage example, assuming you're in a context where you can access example_gen.outputs['examples']
tfrecord_files = [artifact.uri for artifact in example_gen.outputs['examples'].get()][0] + "/Split-eval/*"
print(tfrecord_files )
all_files = tf.io.gfile.glob(tfrecord_files)
print("all_files : ", all_files)
filtered_files = [file for file in all_files if file.endswith('.gz')]
print("filtered_files : ", filtered_files)
image_batch_dataset = get_dataset_from_tfrecords(filtered_files)
print("image_batch_dataset: ", image_batch_dataset)

num_elements = 0
for _ in image_batch_dataset:
    num_elements += 1

# Initialize counters
correct_predictions = 0
total_predictions = 0

# print("Number of batches in the dataset:", num_elements)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

infer = loaded_model.signatures["serving_default"]
input_name = list(infer.structured_input_signature[1].keys())[0]
output_name = list(infer.structured_outputs.keys())[0]
print("input_name", input_name)
print("output_name", output_name)

for image_batch, label_batch in image_batch_dataset:
    # print(loaded_model.signatures["serving_default"])
    input_data = {input_name: image_batch}
    infer = loaded_model.signatures["serving_default"]

    predictions = infer(**input_data)
    # predictions = loaded_model.signatures["serving_default"](input_2=image_batch)
    # print(predictions)
    # predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions['quant_dense_1'].numpy(), axis=1)
    predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions[output_name].numpy(), axis=1)
    
    print("predicted_classes", predicted_classes)
    print("label_batch.numpy()", label_batch.numpy())
    # print("label_batch.shape[0]", label_batch.shape[0])
    # Update counters
    correct_predictions += np.sum(predicted_classes == label_batch.numpy())
    total_predictions += label_batch.shape[0]

print("correct_predictions", correct_predictions)
print("total_predictions", total_predictions)

accuracy = correct_predictions / total_predictions
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy: .2f}")

Name of your Organization (Optional)
Other info / logs
Any help will be appreiciated
